# How to Hash Value in Flutter Using SHA256?

Tags: algorithm, hash, dart, flutter, sha256

Hashing Value (String or Int OR etc...) in Flutter ## **Heading** ##

I have Value like  "Almahery"

How to Hash in in SHA 256 ?

Answer (score 50):

1. Import (Crypto) :

   ```
    import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
   ```
2. Then add this code:

   ```
    var bytes1 = utf8.encode("Almahery");         // data being hashed
    var digest1 = sha256.convert(bytes1);         // Hashing Process
    print("Digest as bytes: ${digest1.bytes}");   // Print Bytes
    print("Digest as hex string: $digest1");      // Print After Hashing
   ```

Comment: Here's a bonus: ```var output = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(input)).toString()```

Answer (score 2):

let you want convert ***apple*** to ***SHA256*** String

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
var appleInBytes = utf8.encode("apple");
String value = sha256.convert(appleInBytes);
print(value.toString());
 |
 |
\|/
result
===>  "3a7bd3e2360a3d29eea436fcfb7e44c735d117c42d1c1835420b6b9942dd4f1b"
```